# WebGL fragment shader color not taking effect

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have this piece of code:

```
var FSHADER_SOURCE = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 u_FragColor;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;
  }`;
```

Also a function to change color for fragment shader:

```
var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');

// lines to set rgb
gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]);
```

Weirdly, I can see rgb is set to something like `[0,1,0,1]` but color for fragment shader is black anyway. Even if I change the code to:

```
// still black
gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

The only way to change color is to directly modify rgb channels without using `u_FragColor`. What am I missing here?

---

Also complete code is on [gist](https://gist.github.com/KHN190/9162f3d04b0e7f27c9323b4b4b13970f) if helpful.

Comment: I don't see the `gl.program` value being set anywhere in your gist so the `gl.getUniformLocation` call is not doing what you think it should do.  `gl.program` is not a built-in value in WebGL so unless you set it, it has no value. Probably you meant to pass in the compiled program?

Comment: @HuyNguyen It's set by `initShaders`, which is a helper provided by the book [WebGL Programming Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/). I can inspect it using `console.log`. And if it's not set, how could vertex shader work? It's only fragment shader uniform parameter not passing to it.

Answer (score 2):

An active program resource, like the location of a uniform variable, can be get after the program was linked:

```js
gl.linkProgram(gl.program);
var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
```

But, to set the value of a uniform variable, the program has to installed as the current program. [`uniform`*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.10) sets a values to the uniform which is associated to the location of the currently used program. Note, `gl.uniform4f` has no parameter for the program, the affected program is the current program:

```js
gl.useProgram(gl.program);
gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I am doing something like this:

```
var color = new Float32Array([rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]]);
```

...and then:

```
gl.uniform4fv(program.uniforms['u_fragColor'], color);
```

So, I believe the issue here is just only the conversion inside `uniform4f` instead of `uniform4fv`.

Please note, later on You can just set the color components directly to the `Float32Array`, no need to allocate every time a new one.

Comment: You don't need to use a `Float32Array` with `gl.uniform`. A native JavaScript array will work just fine

Comment: Probably it's browser related? Thanks for help but both solutions don't work for me.